# I am not able to understand how to use IVotes contract address in GovernorVotes contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, chai, openzeppelin

As IVotes is a interface and cannot be  deployed.

```
    IVotes public immutable token;

    constructor(IVotes tokenAddress) {
        token = tokenAddress;
    }
....
```

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"IVotes" is an abstract contract or an interface and cannot be deployed.

- Import abstractions into the '.sol' file that uses them instead of deploying them separately.
- Contracts that inherit an abstraction must implement all its method signatures exactly.
- A contract that only implements part of an inherited abstraction is also considered abstract.

I want to use IVotes address passing in GovernorVotes constructor.
I tried bunch of methods but none works

Answer (score 1):

The Solidity snippet, that you shared, expects a contract on the `tokenAddress` to **implement** the `IVotes` interface.

But it needs to be a "full" contract with all function bodies - not just the function declarations.

Comment: it require the deployed contract address as a parameter which i am not able to understand how to get it as it is a interface contract(cannot be deployed).

Comment: @YaksheshGupta You need to either obtain the address of an existing contract (that implements the interface) or create the contract yourself (again a contract that implements the interface).... Please note that there is a difference between an interface (doesn't have the function bodies - only function names, input params and output params) and a contract (does have function bodies). A simple description is also that a contract implements an interface by creating the function bodies for the function names declared in the interface.

Comment: I made a contract that usses all the function of the interface and its working now, Thanks